# How to patch a class in a Python unittest, that is used in an inner method?

Tags: python, unit-testing, monkeypatching

Given a scenario where I have a Flask application that has a route to get resources from a database, there are three files:

1. The Flask "main" app, with the endpoints (api.py)
2. A database class, to handle connections (database.py)
3. A domain class for specific resources (resource.py)

The api file looks like this:

```py
from src.objects.resource import Resource

@api.route('/api/resource/<id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_resource(id):
    records = Resource().query(id)
    return records
```

The `Resource` object has, in its constructor, an instance of the database class being constructed:

```py
class Resource(Database):
    def __init__(self):
        Database.__init__(self, 'resource')
```

And the `Database` class connects to the database on `__init__`:

```py
class Database:
    def __init__(self, entity):
        self.conn = psycopg2.connect(os.getenv('DB_URI', 'localhost'))
```

---

What I really want right now is to create a unit test to mock what happens when the API method `get_resource` is hit (not what happens with an HTTP call in, but what happens with both valid and invalid ids being provided as arguments).

Since the Resource object is acting mostly as an interface to database retrieval right now, I would like to mock it in my test, so when the method constructs an instance of `Resource` it gets the mock during the test, not the actual Resource instance.

However, what I'm seeing is that the real constructors are being called. The test code is as follows:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
import json
import src.api
from flask import Flask


class TestApi(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('src.objects.resource.Resource')
    def test_get_resource(self, mock_obj):

        # given
        instance = mock_obj.return_value
        instance.query.return_value = {
            'id': 1,
            'name': 'Resource\'s Name'
        }

        # when
        with Flask(__name__).app_context():
            # then
            result = json.loads(src.api.get_resource(1).get_data())

            self.assertEqual(True, 'data' in result)
            self.assertEqual(True, 'error' in result)
            self.assertEqual(False, result['error'])
```

And I am getting a `ProgrammingError` from the `psycopg2` module (which I don't want to be called):

```
E psycopg2.ProgrammingError: invalid dsn: missing "=" after "localhost" in connection info string
```

---

Should I mock the `__init__` method of the Resource object? If so, how?

Comment: You have to patch the name within the module where it's being used, not the module where it came from.  So `src.api.Resource`, I think, rather than `src.objects.resource.Resource`.

Comment: @Samwise could you elaborate a bit more on that? What you are saying is that the patch should be done within the method, not from the unit test?

Comment: @Samwise cesource.py is inside a directory with other resources. Inside of this directory there is a __init__.py file too. So when I replace the patch, the error is that "init.py does not have the attribute Resource".